# Grep Regex - Words in brackets?

Tags: regex, grep

I want to know the regex in **grep** to match everything that isn't a specific word.  I know how to not match everything that isn't a *single* character,

```
gibberish blah[^.]*jack
```

That would match blah, jack and everything in between as long as the in between didn't contain a period.  But is it possible to do something like this?

```
gibberish blah[^joe]*jack
```

Match blah, jack and everything in between as long as the in between didn't contain the word "joe"?

**UPDATE:**
I can also use AWK if that would better suit this purpose.

So basically, I just want to get the sentence "gibberish blah other words jack", as long as "joe" isn't in the other words.

**Update 2 (The Answer, to a different question):**

Sorry, I am tired.  The sentence actually can contain the word "joe", but not two of them.  So "gibberish blah jill joe moo jack" would be accepted, but "gibberish blah jill joe moo joe jack" wouldn't.
Anyway, I figured out the solution to my problem.  Just grep for "gibberish.*jack" and then do a word count (wc) to see how many "joes" are in that sentence.  If wc comes back with 1, then it's ok, but if it comes back with 2 or more, the sentence is wrong.

So, sorry for asking a question that wouldn't even solve my problem.  I will mark sputnick's answer as the right one, since his answer looks like it would solve the original posts problem.

Comment: No, regex doesn't let you do that.  The stuff inside square brackets is a *set*.  There's no way to negate an atom in BRE or ERE.  Though you might be able to do this in PCRE.

Comment: This is not clear. It should match "blah" or "blahish" first ? oO

Comment: @sputnick You are right, that isn't clear. I will edit it.

Comment: Have you tested `grep -v` like I explain in my POST ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is named *look around*, it's an advanced `regex` technique in `pcre` & `perl`. It's used in modern languages. [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) can handle this expressions if you have the `-P` switch. If you don't have `-P`, try `pcregrep` instead. (or any modern language).

See

- http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444
- http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

**NOTE**

If you just want to *negate* a `regex`, maybe a simple `grep -v "regex"` will be sufficient. (It depends of your needs) :

```
$ echo 'gibberish blah other words jack' | grep -v 'joe'
gibberish blah other words jack
$ echo 'gibberish blah joe other words jack' | grep -v 'joe'
$
```

See

```
man grep | less +/invert-match
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the negative lookbehind syntax:

```
blahish blah(?<!joe)*jack
```

Comment: only in PCRE.  The OP hasn't said what form of RE he's using.  Best to qualify answers that are technology-specific.

Comment: The OP mentions grep. As such this is possibly not a valid answer. On the other hand, Perl does have a grep function ;)

Comment: Sorry, I said grep in the title.  I should have clarified in the post also.  Yes I am using grep.